# Calling a View from Controller present in external dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dll file for external controllers as external.dll present in bin folder of the application.

The code for controller is as follows

```
namespace External.Controllers
{
    public class ExternalController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult CustomerView() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ViewResult SupplierView()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

if i am routing initially it in global.asax file as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL 
    new { controller = "External", action = "CustomerView" });
```

The controller method is called and page is loaded.

**Problem:** I dont want the page to be called initially as default, but at the later stage in the application on User request.
So when the page is called as /External/CustomerView, it is not able to find that method.
and it is throwing following error:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I have tried this also

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Common", action = "Login" },
    new[] { "External.Controllers" });
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say that it works, then you say you tried another method that does not work.  The logical answer is to avoid using the second method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Please see the edit made

Comment: Is the "External" part of the route what distinguishes the user requests from the others?  Note that you can define more than one route.

Comment: Have you seen http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/11/14/how-to-call-controllers-in-external-assemblies-in-an-asp.net.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a VirtualPathProvider that knows how to read a view from an assembly's embedded resources. See http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/loading-asp-net-mvc-controllers-and-views-from-an-assembly.